# How to copy files from specific time range?

Tags: file, date, vbscript, copy, datediff

I got a folder with files that are created every day, there are few difrent types of files (txt, msg, etc.) in that folder, but I need to come up with a script that allows me to copy a specific file, let's say msg file form 2015-05-05. There are some time windows in which these files are appearing, like after 10 AM there will be a txt file but not soner and so on.

My script asks user to input a date, for example 2015-05-05, on which file should be copied. Script adds to that date a hour stamp (10:00:00 PM), so the "cut off" date is going to be: 2015-05-05 10:00:00 PM.
Then I'm using `DateDiff` with an hour interval of 12, script cross everythinng interval, "cut off date" and creation date of txt files and copies them to another folder.
BUT, it copies all txt files that meet that requirements, so all files that where created between 10am and 10pm regardless of day, month and year. I need to copy only txt file from that specific day!
What can I do to make that script to check a time window, something like 2015-05-05 10:00:00 PM ±12 hours? I need a way to make a time range, the center of that range will be a 10 PM of a day that user will mark, exemple 2015-05-05, and from that point (2015-05-05 10:00:00 PM) I need to check ±12 hours.

Here is my script, but its not working the way I want:

```
Dim inputday

sourcepath = "C:\EveryDayFiles\"
NewFolder = "C:\Copy\EDF"

Do
    inputday = InputBox ("Type in a date:", "Copy Date")
    If inputday = "" Then
        Msgbox "Wrong Date!"
    End If
Loop Until inputday > ""
cutofdate = inputday & " 10:00:00 PM"
Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objfso.GetFolder(sourcepath)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    dFileCrDate = objfso.GetFile(objFile).DateCreated
    If timediff = DateDiff("h", dFileCrDate, Datapodana) =< 12 Then
        If objfso.GetExtensionName(objFile) = "txt" Then
            objfso.GetFile(objFile).Copy NewFolder & "\", True
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply build your date margins by adding and subtracting 12 hours to/from your reference date respectively:

```
refdate = CDate(inputday & " 22:00:00")
mindate = DateAdd("h", -12, refdate)
maxdate = DateAdd("h", 12, refdate)
```

Then check if your files' creation dates are between these margins:

```
For Each objFile In objfso.GetFolder(sourcepath).Files
  If objFile.DateCreated >= mindate And objFile.DateCreated <= maxdate Then
    objFile.copy NewFolder & "\", True
  End If
Next
```

Comment: THX MATE! I was actually thinking about that solution but I've messed up the "mindate" and "maxdate". I really appreciate your help!